# Errors while installing the WSO2 App-factory 2.1

Tags: wso2

Errors while installing the App-factory
[image]
I followed the link : https://docs.wso2.com/display/AF210/Installing+the+Products+on+a+Single+Server
When I run the setup script  it gives me lot of failure message. ( Attached Screenshot While_running_setup_in_single_server) 
sudo bash setup.sh

Comment: image is unclear. can you update the question with copy pasted error log

Comment: Also, not really an answer to your question, but if using App Factory online (as opposed to a local install) is acceptable, you can just sign-up to WSO2 App Cloud: http://wso2.com/cloud/app-cloud - it is the same App Factory product, just hosted by WSO2.